# How to log CharConversionException from HttpServletRequest getParameter

Tags: java, servlets, encoding

From time to time i'm getting this error when calling getParameter on an HttpServletRequest:

```
INFO: Character decoding failed. Parameter [SomeParameter] with value [SomeValue] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
java.io.CharConversionException: isHexDigit
...
```

To find the source of this error I wanted to log the complete request url, but the problem is that you don't "recognize" when the error is thrown because it is catched inside the getParameter method.
Outside of the getParameter method there is no error thrown you could catch and then log.

So is there any way i could catch this encoding error myself?

Note: I know what is causing the error, it's a wrong encoded % inside the parameters. I just don't know where it comes from because it is a very central location in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Tomcat error message.

In case Tomcat cannot parse parameters it sets a special request attribute to `Boolean.TRUE` which you can use to detect faulty parameters:

```
boolean paramParseFailed = 
    request.getAttribute("org.apache.catalina.parameter_parse_failed") != null;
```

Note that this is only set after parameters have been read, since Tomcat populates the parameters lazily.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what i was looking for.